py3dtilesで作成＆マージした3Dタイルを画面(deck.gl)からズームアウトすると一部の3Dタイルしか表示されない。
問題
2つのLASファイルを3Dタイル作成&マージし、マージしたタイルセットを１つのレイヤーに表示するとズームアウト時に先頭の3Dタイルしか表示されない。
質問
全ての3Dタイルが表示されるようにするには、どうすればよいのでしょうか？
試している3Dタイル作成&マージ方法や画面表示方法を提示致しますので、ご教授頂けると助かります。
補足)
現状では、問題の回避方法が分からないため、3Dタイルごとにレイヤーを作成して表示させております。
3Dタイル作成&マージ方法
(1)～(3)を実行し、(3)のマージしたタイルセットを画面表示しております。
(1) 3DタイルA作成
py3dtiles convert --srs_in 6677 --srs_out 4978 /tmp/point-a.las --out /path/point-a

(2) 3DタイルA作成
py3dtiles convert --srs_in 6677 --srs_out 4978 /tmp/point-b.las --out /path/point-b

(3) 3DタイルA,Bマージ
py3dtiles merge /path/point-a/tileset.json /path/point-b/tileset.json --output-tileset /path/merge-tileset.json

画面表示方法
<!doctype html>
<html>
　<head>
　　<meta charset="utf-8">
　　<script src='https://unpkg.com/deck.gl@8.6.4/dist.min.js'>＜/script>
　　<script src="https://unpkg.com/@deck.gl/geo-layers@8.6.4/dist.min.js"></script>
　　<script src="https://unpkg.com/@loaders.gl/3d-tiles@3.0.12/dist/dist.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
const {Deck, Tile3DLayer, TileLayer} = deck;
const tileLayer = new deck.TileLayer({
　data: "https://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
　tileSize: 256,
　renderSubLayers: props => new deck.BitmapLayer(props, {
　　data: null,
　　image: props.data,
　　bounds: (({ west, south, east, north }) => [west, south, east, north])(props.tile.bbox),
　}),
});
const tile3dLayer = new Tile3DLayer({
　id: 'tile3dlayer',
　pointSize: 1,
　data: '/path/merge-tileset.json'
　loader: Tiles3DLoader,
});
const deckgl = new deck.Deck({
　initialViewState: {
　　longitude: 139.75,
　　latitude: 35.69,
　　zoom: 13,
　　pitch: 0,
　　bearing: 0,
　},
　controller: true,
　layers: [tileLayer, tile3dLayer ]
});
</script>
</body>
</html>

